# Bug report: FAQ not editable by moderator

Tags: bug, status-completed

When I try to edit the first section of the FAQ (by clicking on the moderator's "edit" button) nothing happens. Firefox 18.0.1 or IE10.

I can edit the about page.

Comment: I suggest you post this at meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @lkessler, I've been advised to post it here as it only affects this site not all sites.

Comment: @lkessler Correct, bugs and feature-requests should be posted here. Incidentally, I've notified the devs and a fix is imminent.

Answer (score 3):

This was caused by a small typo when we launched the site. It's fixed now. Thanks for the report.